# Wanting to pull a substring from a larger string

Tags: python

Im wanting to pull out a "thank you!" from this string, this is my code so far

```
tweet = ("Twitter,Thank you!,11-15-2017 10:58:18,96,433,false,9307")
import re
twt = ""
twt = re.findall(r',(.*?),',tweet)
print(twt)
```

this is my output

```
['Thank you!', '96', 'false']
```

im not sure why im not only getting "Thank you!"

Comment: You are using `findall()` and it is giving you all of the matches to your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `re.findall` which is giving you all the matches, you can use `re.search` instead:

```
tweet = ("Twitter,Thank you!,11-15-2017 10:58:18,96,433,false,9307")
import re
twt = ""
twt = re.search(r',(.*?),',tweet).group(1)
>>> print(twt)

>>> 'Thank you!'
```